# Font is not getting properly when the HTML file is convert to a PDF?

Tags: html, css, xml, xslt

I have new to work on XSLT Stylesheet. Here XHTML convert into PDF file using someother tool we have it. I have to change the font-family like to change "HelveticaLTStd-Bold", but after file conversion specific font was shown as "Times New Roman" instead of "HelveticaLTStd-Bold" and other style attribute is working good.

Here I attached the code below:

***XHTML:***

```
<table width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="2px" border="0">
   <colgroup><col width="100%" /></colgroup>
   <tbody>                           
     <tr>
        <td style="font-family:'HelveticaLTStd-Bold';" align="center" class="tdheader">
            HEADER
        </td>
     </tr>                                                   
   </tbody>
</table>
```

***overrides.css***

```
.tdheader{
    font-family: 'HelveticaLTStd-Bold' !important;
    color:red;
  }

 @font-face {
    font-family: 'HelveticaLTStd-Bold';
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: normal;
    src: url('HelveticaLTStd-Bold.otf') format('otf');
 }
```

Can you anyone resolve it?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the PDF specific CSS under `@media` like this :

```
@media print{
    td{
          font-family: 'HelveticaLTStd-Bold' !important;
          color:#333
    }
}
```

**Tip :** *If you don't see any results or blank page while print preview try changing color mode from color to black & white or vice versa.*

Comment: why media and print here?, I have converted html to pdf not print  that file. CSS not applied after conversion in pdf

Comment: What PDF creator do you use? Possibly the font is not registered   in that application?